# Tool to reorder Windows context menu items (menuitems) in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, user-interface, desktop-environment, menu

Can anyone recommend a gratis tool to reorder Windows context menu items (aka menuitems) in Windows 7?

Must be gratis (free of cost).

Portable and open-source are both preferred, but neither required.

I tried [NirSoft's ShellExView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html), and although it's a great tool, it cannot reorder menu items.

Answer (score 2):

To do so [manually in the Registry](http://techoqueries.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-change-order-of-options-in.html):

- Locate the context menu item in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`, e.g., fro *Run as Administrator*:

[image: Run as Administrator Reg Key]

- You will likely need to take ownership to make any change to that key.
- Add a DWORD value, `flags`.
- Set the value to `0` to put it in the *Rename* section of the context menu.
- Set the value to `1` to put it in the *Send to* section of the context menu.
- Set the value to `2` to put it in the default position of the context menu.

See also [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007852/order-in-the-windows-explorer-context-menu) for more ways to change the display order.

**N.B.** Hacking the Registry, particularly where ownership must be taken, can be hazardous to your system.

Some of the links suggest alphabetical order applies *within* a section. For the *Start* menu, I've used punctuation and NBSP, char(160), to move items to the top of the list or bottom, but have not tried that for the *Explorer* context menu. Check an [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/), keeping in mind Windows may display some characters oddly or choke on others.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dr. Moishe.  I'm real busy at the moment, and will have some time soon to take a closer look at what you wrote as well as the linked QA.  It might be answered in the other QA, but is there a reliable way to reorder *within a section*?  I'm very good with the Windows Registry, so working directly in it is no problem.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket, see changes regarding alphabetical order. P.S. - Nice moniker: Mask It or Casket!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket did you get time to check this out? Is it an acceptable answer?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica The info in the answer is all quite helpful and accurate (hence my upvote!).  I'm hoping that someone will know of a software tool that automates the process to make it more time-efficient.  I haven't personally found such a tool, but I'm hopeful there's one out there.